# Connecting with mongodb in openshift is showing error.

Tags: java, mongodb, openshift

I am developing a project based on java and mongodb. MongoDb is my backend, but when I try to connect it, says

```
[ERROR] /var/lib/openshift/someclass.java: error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]  package com.mongodb
```

I know this is a problem in Maven build as it cant find the methods and classes in my DBconnect class.
Please tell me how to solve the problem. I need to figure out as soon as possible. How to include my jar in maven repo and upload to openshift.

Answer (score 1):

Double check that your dependencies are listed correctly in your pom.xml

Answer (score 1):

If you can't or don't want to add the dependency to your pom.xml file, try following this KB article about how to add the jar file to your project: https://www.openshift.com/kb/kb-e1087-how-to-include-libraries-jar-files-in-your-java-application-without-using-maven